# How to configure the "changelog against a specific branch" with the GIT plugin in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

My configuration :

**Name of the repository** : git@bitbucket.org:xyz/Jenkins-Build

**Name of the Branch** : $BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH (which one is coming with the pull request from bitbucket

[image: Configuration]

This is the Output of the configuration :

> Using 'Changelog to branch' strategy. fatal: bad revision
>   '^git@bitbucket.org:xyz/Jenkins-Build' ERROR: Unable to retrieve
>   changeset hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error: git whatchanged
>   --no-abbrev -M "--format=commit %H%ntree %T%nparent %P%nauthor %aN <%aE> %ai%ncommitter %cN <%cE> %ci%n%n%w(0,4,4)%B" -n 1024
>   1ebf4e2e54b895fd2fadf4a22edd2972fafc0669
>   ^git@bitbucket.org:xyz/$BITBUCKET_SOURCE_BRANCH in
>   /home/jwilson/Jenkins/workspace/nexus-cloud   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$6.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1176)
>     at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.computeChangeLog(GitSCM.java:1305)     at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1217)  at
>   hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1206)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
>     at
>   jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1838)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)